# Unknown warning generated in rmarkdown to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have been happily generating PDF files from RMarkdown files for a while now. Recently, when the PDF file is created, there is a new warning that I don't understand - it appears *only* in the PDF file (i.e., there's no output in the .Rmd file that shows the same message). The error is:

`## Warning in !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::$output`
`## %in% : 'length(x) = 3 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'`

I've never seen anything that looks like this, and after Googling it for a while, I found nothing that seemed to be of use. I've tried this in fresh R sessions, and the warning is the same. All of my packages are up to date, and I'm running R version 4.2.1.

Any ideas on how to address this? Or (since it's "just a warning") how to stop it from generating the message in my PDF?

For reference, here is the yaml section of the .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Title Notebook"
author:
   - Name
date: "Last compiled on `r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    highlight: tango
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    extra_dependencies:
      array: null
      caption: null
      graphicx: null
      siunitx: null
      multirow: null
      calc: null
      tabularx: null
      threeparttable: ["para", "online", "flushleft"]
      hyperref: null
  html_notebook:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    df_print: paged
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    df_print: paged
classoption: "nopatch"
```

Here is the setup chunk:

````
```{r setup, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = 'hide'}
# Packages/Libraries can go here:

# Options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
      echo = TRUE,
#      echo = FALSE,
      collapse = TRUE,
      warning = FALSE,
      message = FALSE,
      comment = "#>",
      fig.retina = 2, # Control using dpi
      fig.width = 6,  # generated images
      fig.pos = "t",  # pdf mode
      fig.align = "center",
      dpi = 300,
      out.width = "100%",
      dev = "png",
      optipng = "-o1 -quiet")
```
````

Comment: You should be able to do `warning = F` and `message = F` in your chunk header

Comment: Can you include the yaml section of the R markdown file from which the above warning is generated?!

Comment: @HanselPalencia - I don't know which chunk produces this warning - it's like it comes from the yaml section?

Answer (score 1):

To stop this warning from generating in your pdf output, add `warning=FALSE` in your setup chunk,

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE)
```
````

#### Update

Now it seems that `kableExtra` package is creating that Warnings. If we just ignore the reasons behind this, get rid of the warnings just for now, we can do this,

```
suppressWarnings(library(kableExtra))
```

Then we have this clean warning free output,

[image: warings_free]

Comment: This looks like it already exists in my file. Here's my setup chunk: 
```
# Packages/Libraries can go here:

# Options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
      echo = TRUE,
#      echo = FALSE,
      collapse = TRUE,
      warning = FALSE,
      message = FALSE,
      comment = "#>",
      fig.retina = 2, # Control using dpi
      fig.width = 6,  # generated images
      fig.pos = "t",  # pdf mode
      fig.align = "center",
      dpi = 300,
      out.width = "100%",
      dev = "png",
      optipng = "-o1 -quiet")

```

Comment: The line breaks didn't come across, but the code works with them as they currently exist; see updated post (above).

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg, see my update and try that and let me know.

Comment: Still getting the same warning in the pdf file.

Comment: Unfortunately,  botha of the options works for me. In short I can't reproduce your error. Sorry dont know any better. Another thing you could do, is to host all files in a github repo and share the link. So that people here can check if only you are okay with sharing your files. @KarlWolfschtagg

Comment: I've put the files in https://github.com/Doc-Midnight/Test_Dir - there is an .Rmd file and the PDF output.

Comment: I've gone through the various packages, and it seems that kableExtra is causing the warning.

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg, Yes Now I can reproduce the error. Yes you are right

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg, I have updated my answer and also made a [pull request](https://github.com/Doc-Midnight/Test_Dir/pull/1), merge that PR and work on the file, you are good to go.